# combineLatest behaviour in Rxjs 5?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5, combinelatest

Looking at the [*definition*](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-combineLatest) of `combineLatest`

> Combines multiple Observables to create an Observable whose values are
>   calculated from the latest values of each of its input Observables.

or

> Whenever any input Observable emits a value, it computes a formula
>   using the latest values from all the inputs, then emits the output of
>   that formula.

[image]

It's pretty clear to see that at each period of time / emission , the result at that emission is the combination of the latest  emissions.

If so , looking at this code

```
const obs1 = Rx.Observable.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
const obs2 = Rx.Observable.of('a', 'b', 'c')
const obs3 = obs2.combineLatest(obs1, (a, b) => a+b);

const subscribe = obs3.subscribe(latestValues => {
  console.log(latestValues   );
});
```

The result is :

```
c1,c2,c3,c4,c5
```

And when I change

```
obs2.combineLatest(obs1..
```

to

```
obs1.combineLatest(obs2..
```

— I get `5a,5b,5c`

**Question:**

The docs don't specify any difference regarding  the order of invocation (if so - why do I get different results) ?

Why don't I see other combinations with the other source ? It seems that one source is taking its last value and *only then* -  join it to each value from the OTHER source.

It seems like that this is what actually happening:

```
[other source]---a---b---c------------------------
[first source]-------------1----2-----3-----4----5
[result]-------------------c1---c2----c3----c4---c5
```

And when I swap the order (obs1<->obs2) :

```
[first source]-----1--2---3--4--5----------------
[other source]---------------------a-----b------c
[result]---------------------------5a----5b-----5c
```

What's going on here? why does one stream has to finish in order for the join to start ?

Why don't I see something like this ( or a variation) :

```
[first source]-----1-----2--------3-------4------5---
[other source]---------a-----b------c----------------
[result]---------------1a------2b------3b---4c-------5c
```

[**JSBIN**](http://jsbin.com/wufokeqemo/1/edit?html,js,console)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because values from your source Observables are emited synchronously unless you use a Scheduler. This means that first `obs1` emits all values and only the last one is remembered by `combineLatest` and than `obs2` starts emiting all its values (the same appplies if you switch the two Observables). Now the `combineLatest` has values for both Observables so any emission from the second Observables will make the operator emit a value.

Why it works like this is because `Observable.of` is implemented as `ArrayObservable` internally and by default it doesn't use any Scheduler. This means that all its emissions happen synchronously. See https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/observable/ArrayObservable.ts#L118

Btw, you can add `Rx.Scheduler.async` as the last parameter to both source Observables.

Comment: So rx4 would've emit different results?

Comment: I think RxJS 4 is using by default so called *immediate* scheduler so the result would be very likely different to rxJS 5.